# Unable to free up space on internal storage, removing cache & apps has no effect

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, installation, insufficient-memory

new to Android Stack Exchange. - Average Android user.

I have a storage problem on my phone. When I try to install an app via Play Store it says there isn't enough free space available, e.g. it is 45mb short. Play Store then offers an option to uninstall other apps to clear up space. So, I select a large app (of e.g. 130mb) and allow PlayStore to uninstall it. It then removes the selected up succefully. However, after doing so it still fails on installing the newly selected app, claiming again it is short on free space (still claiming to be 45mb short).

This has caused a situation in which I have deleted pretty much all my apps but Play Store still refuses to install any new app or any update because it claims to be short on space.

When I go to `Settings`-> `Storage and USB`-> `Internal Storage` it reports that 4.09GB out of 4.54GB is used. However, in the details below it only reports that 2.39GB is used for Apps and 5.33MB is used for cache (which I've cleared many times allready, hoping it would solve the problem). But this means that I am unable to diagnose where 4.09GB-2.39GB-5.33MB = 1.7GB of disk space is apparently being used for...

I tried connecting my phone to my laptop via USB, in order to be able to browse the internal memory but somehow when I use MTP I am only able to browse my phone's SD-storage via my laptop. The internal storage directories simply do not show up and I am left clueless on how to get any access to them..

I am looking for any insights or any tips on how to further diagnose what the problem might be..

> Phone details:
>
> Moto G3
>
> Android 6.0.1
>   Kernel: 3.10.49-g2e9678a

Comment: I believe that that missing space is the system files. Unfortunately without rooting the device you can't really do anything about that. Try using an app like SD Maid, which can remove various junk and temp files safely (SD Maid is one of the best cleaner apps out there). You can use its "Corpse Finder", System Cleaner", AppCleaner", and "Databases" features to reclaim some space back.